Issue with `row_spec()` from `kableExtra` in `modelsummary`
I am trying to create regression table using fixest and modelsummary, but when I run the modelsummary along with the row_spec() function from kableExtra, it shows the following error -
Error in if (kable_format %in% c("pipe", "markdown")) { : 
  argument is of length zero

here is a reproducible example -
mtcars_model = fixest::feols(mpg ~ hp+disp+drat+wt|factor(cyl)+factor(vs), data = mtcars, cluster=~gear)
modelsummary(mtcars_model, fmt = 3, 
             estimate = "{estimate}{stars}",
             statistic = 'statistic', 
             gof_map = c('nobs', 'adj.r.squared'),
             stars = c("*" = 0.10, "**"=0.05, "***"=0.01)
             ) %>% 
  kableExtra::row_spec(1, extra_css = "border-bottom: 2px solid")


Yesterday, I ran the same model, it worked but today it is not working. My session info is here
R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

time zone: America/Chicago
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] kableExtra_1.4.0   modelsummary_2.0.0 fixest_0.12.0     
 [4] estimatr_1.0.4     sandwich_3.1-0     lfe_3.0-0         
 [7] Matrix_1.6-5       janitor_2.2.0      haven_2.5.4       
[10] lubridate_1.9.3    forcats_1.0.0      stringr_1.5.1     
[13] dplyr_1.1.4        purrr_1.0.2        readr_2.1.5       
[16] tidyr_1.3.1        tibble_3.2.1       ggplot2_3.5.0     
[19] tidyverse_2.0.0    groundhog_3.2.0   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tidyselect_1.2.1    viridisLite_0.4.2   fastmap_1.1.1      
 [4] bayestestR_0.13.2   digest_0.6.35       estimability_1.5   
 [7] timechange_0.3.0    lifecycle_1.0.4     dreamerr_1.4.0     
[10] magrittr_2.0.3      compiler_4.3.1      rlang_1.1.3        
[13] tools_4.3.1         utf8_1.2.4          data.table_1.15.4  
[16] knitr_1.46          bit_4.0.5           xml2_1.3.6         
[19] tinytable_0.2.1     withr_3.0.0         numDeriv_2016.8-1.1
[22] datawizard_0.10.0   grid_4.3.1          fansi_1.0.6        
[25] xtable_1.8-4        colorspace_2.1-0    future_1.33.1      
[28] emmeans_1.10.0      globals_0.16.2      scales_1.3.0       
[31] insight_0.19.10     cli_3.6.2           mvtnorm_1.2-3      
[34] rmarkdown_2.26      crayon_1.5.2        generics_0.1.3     
[37] rstudioapi_0.16.0   future.apply_1.11.1 performance_0.11.0 
[40] tzdb_0.4.0          parameters_0.21.6   parallel_4.3.1     
[43] stringmagic_1.1.0   vctrs_0.6.5         hms_1.1.3          
[46] bit64_4.0.5         Formula_1.2-5       listenv_0.9.1      
[49] systemfonts_1.0.6   glue_1.7.0          parallelly_1.37.0  
[52] codetools_0.2-19    stringi_1.8.3       gtable_0.3.5       
[55] tables_0.9.25       munsell_0.5.1       pillar_1.9.0       
[58] htmltools_0.5.8.1   R6_2.5.1            vroom_1.6.5        
[61] evaluate_0.23       lattice_0.22-6      backports_1.4.1    
[64] snakecase_0.11.1    Rcpp_1.0.12         svglite_2.1.3      
[67] nlme_3.1-164        checkmate_2.3.1     xfun_0.43          
[70] zoo_1.8-12          pkgconfig_2.0.3  

By the way, I used groundhog package to load necessary packages that I did not do yesterday. That is the only difference between yesterday and today. Here is the groundhog code -
pkgs <- c (
  'tidyverse', 
  'haven', # to read stat file 
  'lubridate', 
  'janitor', 
  'lfe', 
  'sandwich', 
  'estimatr',
  'fixest', 
  'modelsummary',
  'kableExtra'
)

date <-  "2024-04-23"
library(groundhog)
groundhog.library(pkgs, date)


I have been able to fix it following the answers here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78422275/argument-is-of-length-zero-from-kableextra-after-updating-rstudio?rq=2
